# SharePoint web application port

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, web-application, ssl

I will create a web application with ssl enable,

which port could I configure it when I create the web application? Port 80 or 443 ?

Comment: why downvote!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a practice Port 80 used for http and 443 for https, But you can use the custom ports as per your requirements.

If you are configuring the SSL for Web application then use 443. Here is good guide for configuring SSL for web application.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fabdulwahab/2013/01/20/configure-ssl-for-sharepoint-2013/